# CursorLoader with static rows

Tags: android

I am using a cursor loader to query a local sqlite database into a listview. I would like to add a few static cells to the top of the listview (static as they are not queried from the databse... the values will be populated hard coded). For iPhone developers, this is somewhat like a different section in a UITableView, which you can populate according to the section's index. Is there anyway to achieve this in android (while using a CursorLoader)?

**Edit (part of my code):**

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_contacts, null,
            DbContract.CONTACTS_FIELDS_DISPLAY,
            new int[] { R.id.category_name, R.id.category_image });

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
   }

  public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

          return new CursorLoader(this, DbContract.URI_CATEGORIES,
                  DbContract.CATEGORIES_FIELDS, null, null, CategoriesTable.KEY_NAME);
}
```

Comment: why to don't put this data in database ??

Comment: mohammed - static rows in a database just for presentational purposes doesn't sound right...

Comment: @pskink, I can't find a place to use it... onCreateLoader creates a CursorLoader, how can I provide a MergeCursor? (edited my post to contain a snippet of my code)

Comment: onLoadFinished is that place

Comment: what you probably want to do is to `addFooterView` you in your listView, or just create a CustomAdapter that tricks out the view position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say use a CursorWrapper or a MatrixCursor and a MergeCursor together. You can override/extend the CursorLoader loadInBackground.

```
return new CursorLoader(this, DbContract.URI_CATEGORIES,
              DbContract.CATEGORIES_FIELDS, null, null, CategoriesTable.KEY_NAME) {
    Cursor loadInBackground () {
      .... do work here combining result of super.loadInBackground ();
    };
```